# Replace the same class div and has no ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]

I have four DIVS, one is ready and the other three are still hidden. When the link to the second div is pressed, I want the second div to show up, and so for the next link.

The problem is, all the four DIV **doesn't have** ID and has the same class.

I just want it to automatically run without knowing what is the ID and the class of the div, or anything inside the div. It may look like a slideshow but on click function.

```
<p> link to the ready div </P> 
<p> link to the second div </P>
<p> link to the third div </P>
<p> link to the last div </P>


 <div id="wrapper">

<div> this is the div that is ready. This div has no ID and has the same class with others <div>

<div> this is the second div that is hidden. This div has no ID and has the same class with others <div>

<div> this is the third div that is hidden. This div has no ID and has the same class with others <div>

<div> this is the last div that is hidden. This div has no ID and has the same class with others <div>

 </div>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Alkasih/jKDz8/2/)

Comment: Cool pic bruvoo, where is the code? `:)` chuck in a fiddle if you can

Comment: look at an index based solution

Comment: By the way you misspelt "wrapper" as "wraper", so now you sound like a rapist.

Comment: @Tats_innit I update the question with fiddle, please...

Comment: Not 100% sure what your asking but you looking for something like this? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/jKDz8/3/)

Comment: @Ruddy Your fiddle is almost there. But you didn't hide the previous div when the next div is shown. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im pretty sure this is what you are looking for.

**jQuery**

```
$(".options p").click(function () {
    var ourPick = $("p").index(this) + 1;
    $(".container div:nth-child(" + ourPick + ")").show();
});
```

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/jKDz8/4/)

So what we are doing is getting the index for the link pressed and then using that to select the `div` we want to show (this is using `:nth-child()`).

**Note:** I have put a container around the links so you it doesn't pick up every `p` on the page.

---

If you want only one at a time you can just set them all to hide before showing one.

**jQuery:**

```
$(".options p").click(function () {
    var ourPick = $("p").index(this) + 1;
    $(".container div").hide();
    $(".container div:nth-child(" + ourPick + ")").show();
});
```

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/jKDz8/5/)

Comment: Can you help me again. I want it now to have a slideshow function, which it means that all the RED hidden div will show and change automatically in five minutes (so I don't have to click the button to show the hidden DIV, but the botton is still there in case the user want to move it manually on hover. I still want you to use your code, I have update it here. http://jsfiddle.net/Alkasih/pN73Z/

Comment: @inandout To be honest you are better off just using someone else's jQuery sideshow. There are some amazing ones out there just have a little look around.

Answer (score 3):

i have made a fiddle that might suite your case please have a look. You can make some modifications according to your needs.

```
var currentDiv = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".container div").click(function(){
        $(".container div").eq(currentDiv+1).css( "display", "block" );
        currentDiv++;
    })
});
```

[JSFIddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/7F8Vn/)

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle, but I have to update it and the right fiddle looks like this http://jsfiddle.net/Alkasih/jKDz8/

Comment: No, man. Look at my picture above. In the righ side, there are four buttons that refer to each divs in the left side.

Comment: ok, i made a few changes... look at it [Jsfiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/7F8Vn/5/)

Answer (score 1):

[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/6Vcfa/)

**Explanation**

```
<div class="parentDiv">
  <div class="div">1</div>
  <div class="div">2</div>
  <div class="div">3</div>
  <div class="div">4</div>
</div>

<div class="buttons">
   <a idx="1">1</a> 
   <a idx="2">2</a> 
   <a idx="3">3</a> 
   <a idx="4">4</a> 
</div>

$('.buttons a').click(
  function(event)
{
    var idx = $(event.target).attr('idx');
    $('.div').hide(); //Hides all the divs
    $('.parentDiv div:nth-child('+idx+')').show();  // Shows required div
}
);
```

**DISADVANTAGE**

If you will insert more contents, there is more work. Else no problem..
If you insert a div , you have to change all the links.

```
 <div class="parentDiv">
  <div class="div">1</div>
    <div class="div">2.0 Inserted Div</div>   
  <div class="div">2</div>
  <div class="div">3</div>
  <div class="div">4</div>
</div>

<div class="buttons">
   <a idx="1">1</a> 
   <a idx="2">2.0</a>
   <a idx="3">2</a>   
   <a idx="4">3</a> 
   <a idx="5">4</a> 
</div>
```

**Not here , All the idx has to be changed. Since my code uses nth-child property**

**Edited**
   [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/6Vcfa/1/)
   [Another Update](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/6Vcfa/2/)

Comment: Thnks for the effort. but your fiddle shows all divs.

Comment: Your editted fiddle is almost there. But why at first the link that refer to each div is hidden? I want all the link is shown up..

Comment: I can't get you. initial fiddle that i created i have shown you all the links .

Comment: The link is shown one by one. The second link is shown when the first link is clicked and so on.

Comment: YES! THat's it! But I dont understand what do you mean by DISADVANTEGE.

Comment: Upvoted answer is same as my fiddle that is specified in the answer. Isn't?

Comment: I meant that if you want to add a div in between div1 and div2. So u need to update 'idx' of all the links by +1.

Comment: DISADVANTAGE If you insert a div , you have to change all the links.  do you mean like this:  `<a idx="5">5</a> ???`

Comment: @inandout This is not the best way for this. This is pretty much given them id's. Check my answer for a way without setting id's.